# Unable to parse the JSON returned by the server: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Tags: asp.net, web-services, extjs4

am working with ExtJs 4.0.

I am trying to fetch data from database from web service and trying to set in grid panel but getting following error **Ext.Error: Unable to parse the JSON returned by the server: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:**

extjs code:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloExt',
    launch: function() {
        // Model definition and remote store (used Ext examples data)
        Ext.define('ForumThread', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['countryId', 'countryName'],
            idProperty: 'countryId'
        });

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            pageSize: 20,
            model: 'ForumThread',
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '../reports/report.asmx/display',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
                 //url: '/grid.json',
                reader: {    
                    root: 'Data',          
                    type: 'json'
                }
            }
        });

        // Define grid that will automatically restore its selection after store reload
        Ext.define('PersistantSelectionGridPanel', {
            extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel'

        });

        // Create instance of previously defined persistant selection grid panel
        var grid = Ext.create('PersistantSelectionGridPanel', {
            autoscroll: true,
            height: 300,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            //region: 'center',
            store: store,
            multiSelect: true, // Delete this if you only need single row selection
            stateful: true,
            forceFit: true,
            loadMask: false,
            viewConfig: {
                stripeRows: true
            },
            columns:[{
                id: 'countryId',
                text: "countryId",
                dataIndex: 'countryId',
                flex: 1,
                sortable: false
            },{
                text: "countryName",
                dataIndex: 'countryName',
                width: 70,
                align: 'right',
                sortable: true
            } ]
        });
    }
});
```

reports.asmx

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
        [ToolboxItem(false)]
        // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
      [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
 [Serializable]

        public class report : System.Web.Services.WebService
            {

                [WebMethod]
                public string HelloWorld()
                {
                    return "Hello World";
                }
                [WebMethod]
                [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true, XmlSerializeString = false)]
                public string display()
                {
                     employee obj = new employee();

                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                return serializer.Serialize(obj.selectAll_employeeDetail(0, 0, 0));
                }
            }
```

can anyone suggest me... whats the wrong in my code?/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because you wrote some strange, custom JSON serialization that's probably is not right (removing trailing, ending characters? why?)

.NET JSON serialization is simple as that:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
HttpContext.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(Object));
HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

You have to add [Serializable] attribute to class or use .NET type which have that attribute already.

String you are returning must be not valid JSON.

[EDIT]
Curious thing: Asmx services (probably WCF services too because i reversed engineered solution from microsoft AJAX scripts) don't look for 'Accept' header for defining type of response as it should cause RFC for http:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

> The Accept request-header field can be used to specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response.

So this should be enough but with jQuery.ajax it is not. From AJAX scripts I mentioned above I took header Content-Type:

> "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"

with this jQuery worked just fine. So I guess you have to add this header to request and this should work. Strange that [ScriptMethod] attribute is not setting default response for JSON as state http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx:

> Specifies whether the response will be serialized as JSON or as XML. The default is Json. 
>   You also have to force service to work as script service through this header:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields:

> Content-Type   The MIME type of the body of the request (used with POST and PUT requests)

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html:

> The Content-Type entity-header field indicates the media type of the entity-body sent to the recipient

So I guess people in Microsoft would thing doing thing this way: "If you not sending as JSON we would not send this to you too." :)

I hope this will work.

PS: since this is json service if you returning .NET built-in type or your type with [Serializable] attribute you can just return it. There is not need to pre serialize response that will be serialized anyway.

Comment: try a per your guideline..**but still i am getting same error**.. Please check my question. I had done changes as per your guidelines

Comment: Can you post example json your services returning as string.

Comment: Ext.Error: Unable to parse the JSON returned by the server: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"countryId":1.0,"countryName":"India","isDelete":true}]</string>` my json code give me above output and error

Comment: So your json returned from service is inserted into xml? I would say that this is the problem. First check if just this json is proper json string (JSON.parse in browser console). Then Check if your Ext code is correct (some aspx page from server with only this json string and content header: application/json should be enough). And third check if your asmx config is correct since it's returning xml not json.

Comment: yes i know problem is XML but i didnt return xml from any where from webservice?

Comment: .NET 4.5? Maybe this is a bug? Try `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]` since rest is default.

Comment: I have found the solution. See my answer.